# How do I eval a simple math formula inside a MySQL stored _function_?

Tags: mysql, math, eval, formula, stored-functions

Inside my stored *function* I have :

```
formula := "(10+10 * 1000)/12";
```

(a simple math formula, with numbers only, dynamically created as a string)

How do I eval this, and return the result ?

I can't use EXECUTE (not possible inside a stored function) and if I make it a stored procedure and call it from a stored function, I get "Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger" -as if I would have the eval directly inside the function.
I need a stored function, and not a procedure, because I need to call it inside a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no solution to this.
I have applied a "paintfull" workaround in PHP, which I will not display here as it is not the subject of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what using the formula is buying you.  If you're writing a stored procedure, type in the formula and forget the string.

I don't think it's in your interest to make the stored proc that dynamic where the formula being evaluated has to be changing from call to call.

If you must, you'll have to write a parser to break that string up into its constitutive parts, create a parse tree, and then walk the tree to evaluate it.  It's not a trivial problem.  I'd rethink this.

Comment: The formulas are keps in the db. I can't just type in the formula... Creating a parse tree is indeed not trivial, especially as MySQL functions :)

Comment: Bad design, in my opinion.  Maybe you ought to think about putting that functionality in the middle tier.

Comment: Not a bad design, but a necessary one :)