# Eval math expression string with informix

Tags: sql, expression, eval, informix

I need to calculate a math expression from a string.

The String looks like "1.00*1.00*4.00"

How can I do that?

Something like

```
Select field1, field2, EVAL("EXPRESSION") as float from table
```

would be great!

Comment: Hi Dominik, did you try reading the manual?

Comment: Hi, sure, but i didn't find the right place in the manual. can you give me an hint?

Comment: I asked this because your question lacked the basic indication about the research effort you should show when asking here. After re-reading the question, I think its a little difficult to do what you expect to. It might be easier to import data to excel and calculate there... or if someone is generous enough to give you the code for this? this would be generous indeed.

Comment: You could also explain why your question is different from that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331543/how-do-i-eval-a-simple-math-formula-inside-a-mysql-stored-function , or that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938257/how-to-eval-a-select-string-and-execute , otherwise you could get false "duplicate" flags.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're right, the questions you mentioned are similar. but the first one is related to mysql - i hope there is a solution for Informix. within the second one there is no math calculation.

Comment: Excel would be a solution, i'm looking for an SQL solution. If nobody has an idea, my next step is to try Splitting/substring by "*" an do the calcuation. but that looks horrible.

Comment: Something that I'm missing, the "expression" is passed, is it stored on a column or built from several fields? What is the IDS version?

Answer (score 4):

Let us create a test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(
    col1 DECIMAL(10,2),
    col2 DECIMAL(10,2),
    col3 DECIMAL(10,2),
    col4 VARCHAR(250)
);

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (1.0, 1.0, 4.0, "1.00*1.00*4.00")
```

If you are building the expression from columns or even passing the string it is straightforward:

```
SELECT  col1 * col2 * col3  AS from_field,
        1.00*1.00*4.00      AS from_string
FROM    tab1;
```

If the value is stored on a column you have to do it programmatically, here is an example of an SPL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_eval()
    RETURNING DECIMAL(10,2) AS eval;

    DEFINE stmt     VARCHAR(250);
    DEFINE eval_str VARCHAR(250);
    DEFINE eval_dec DECIMAL(10,2);

    FOREACH cur FOR 
        SELECT  col4
        INTO    eval_str
        FROM    tab1 

        LET stmt = "SELECT " || eval_str || " as eval FROM sysmaster:sysdual INTO TEMP tmp_eval WITH NO LOG;";
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;

    END FOREACH

    FOREACH eval FOR
        SELECT  eval
        INTO    eval_dec
        FROM    tmp_eval
            RETURN eval_dec WITH RESUME;
    END FOREACH

    DROP TABLE tmp_eval;

END FUNCTION;

EXECUTE FUNCTION get_eval();
```